# Prevent Arquillian from downloading apache-tomee before each test

Tags: java, maven, testing, jboss-arquillian

I'm new to Arquillian and I'll have to fix some tests in old projects.

I noticed, that for some reason, each time when I run test, Arquillian downloads apache-tomee-1.7.2-webprofile (I switched to newest version 1.7.2).

Is there a way to prevent this behavior? (Maybe I have to add some maven dependency or startup script?) Because it takes forever to run all tests.

Here is my Arquillian config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
            http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

<container qualifier="tomee" default="true">
    <configuration>
        <property name="httpPort">-1</property>
        <property name="stopPort">-1</property>
        <property name="ajpPort">-1</property>
        <property name="simpleLog">true</property>
        <property name="cleanOnStartUp">true</property>
        <property name="dir">target/apache-tomee-remote</property>
        <property name="appWorkingDir">target/arquillian-test-working-dir</property>
    </configuration>
</container>
```

And also maven dependencies for tests (all versions are latest and taken from parent.pom):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-tomee-remote</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>ziplock</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-api</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-api-maven</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-container-test-api</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-core</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: It looks like your remote TomEE installation is under your project's target directory. Does it still redownload if you place it somewhere else or skip the `clean` lifecycle phase?

Comment: Yep, that appears to be the problem. If you skipped the clean it would be fine, or if you move the install directory to somewhere else maven won't remove it you should be fine. You could also switch to an embedded tomee, but that has other trade offs.